# R Sessions Verbosity / Silent R Sessions

Tags: r, global, verbosity

I'm trying to write code that logs only comments that I have excplicity `cat`ed or `print`ed and ignores all the text that some of of the command generate themselves, eg. loading of a library usually generates some text which the end user doesn't care about, but the user cares about a certain calculation that I'm running which I've manually inserted a message for.

I've been using `invisible`, `suppressMessages', and the likes but is there a way to globally declare all these so that the canned messages are suppressed / invisible and only my messages are output to the screen / logs?

Comment: Only explicitly write out the parts you want to a text log file? Discard all of the routine output otherwise?

Comment: On screen. Text log file can be managed with a file name to the `cat`. I don't know if there's way to output messages to a text log file though.

Comment: I've struggled with this problem before. Unfortunately, some packages use `cat` instead of `message`, making things like `suppressMessages` useless, and that's a dead end. Well, technically you can capture all output, parse it and pass on. Maybe you could list some examples?

Comment: @tonytonov - More importantly, `suppressMessages` needs to be called every time messages need to be suppressed. I want to maybe set some global option at the beginning of the session which suppresses all messages by default unless they are explicitly listed in the code that I've typed.

Comment: I know that feel :) IIRC I ended up wrapping my functions (that use other packages) in `suppressMessages`, at least that's something.